# Akka - implement a custom DeadLetterListener actor

Tags: java, scala, akka

I am trying to add additional behaviour for handling dead letters in Akka. I am thinking the best way to do this is by implementing our own dead letter listener, but I can't find any documentation on how to integrate our own actor instead of the default dead letter listener.

Is there any documentation on how to go about doing this (or is there another approach for extending or overriding the behaviour of these default implementations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should subscribe to [EventStream](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.2/scala/event-bus.html#Event_Stream) for this.

```
import akka.actor.{ Actor, DeadLetter, Props }

class Listener extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case d: DeadLetter => println(d)
  }
}

val listener = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[Listener]))
system.eventStream.subscribe(listener, classOf[DeadLetter])
```

Comment: Thanks - in front of me all this time! I also ended up `setting log-dead-letters = 0` in akka.conf to suppress the default listener.